# Getting row sum of the Table

Tags: sql, datatable

Is it possible to take the row sum of the all rows from a datatable in SQL. I have one datatable like this

```
Date             col1           col2       col3
30/7/2012          5              2           3
31/7/2012          2              3           5
01/08/2012         2              4           1
```

but i want to achieve like this by creating one column name Total
like:

```
 Date            Total      col1           col2       col3
30/7/2012         10          5              2           3
31/7/2012         9           1              3           5
01/08/2012        7           2              4           1
```

Is it Possible? If yes please help me for the same.

Comment: It's a columnar sum rather than a row sum ?

Comment: @verisimilitude: i will need each row wise value..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select Date,
       col1 + col2 + col3 as Total,
       col1, col2, col3
  from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) of your Total `DataColumn` to calculate the values in the column as the sum of the values of other columns in each row:

```
var totalColumn = new DataColumn("Total");
// Add your Total column to your DataTable.
dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn);
// The new column will be the second in the DataTable, like your diagram shows.
totalColumn.SetOrdinal(1);
// Use the sum of each row's Col1, Col2 and Col3 for the values in this column.
totalColumn.Expression = "[Col1] + [Col2] + [Col3]";
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Why do you think the OP used it?

Comment: @Tichodroma Good point.  I'm assuming here C# and .NET because he uses the term 'datatable', as opposed to just 'table'.  I'll delete my answer if it's not helpful.